# AngularJS, how to get and set a filter defined in ng-repeat from within controller?

Tags: html, angularjs, cookies, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

The simple HTML block below loops through a list of person objects in JSON format 
to display their first and last names. The two input boxes above the ng-repeat are linked to the filters based on firstName and lastName accordingly. So far all is good, working.

My goal is to capture the user input in filter fields in the controller when they leave the page, and then repopulate the filters when they return to the page. I am able to capture/get the search field values by using $scope.$on("$destroy"... when the page is left. However, when I try to set those fields, $scope.search.firstName = 'John' I am getting an error: $scope.search is undefined. My goal is to use cookies to keep and then reset the filter field values, but I am not sure why the set does not work and how to fix it.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.firstName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.lastName" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in personList | filter:search:strict">
        <td>
            <span class="col-xs-offset-2">
                {{person.firstName}}
            </span>
        </td>


        <td>
            <span class="col-xs-offset-2">
                {{person.lastName}}
            </span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

// fragments from controller

```
$scope.search.firstName = 'John'; // this does not work, returns error

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    console.log($scope.search.firstName); // this works
    console.log($scope.search.lastName)); // this works
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting this `TypeError: $scope.search is undefined`, you should try to set those values by first defining `search` as an object.

```
$scope.search = { 'firstName': '', 'lastName': ''};
$scope.search.firstName = 'John';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, that was the issue, I did not define the search object in the controller, because initially I did not need to access the filter properties in the controller. For me it was just enough to put $scope.search = {}; This would have given access to filter properties, firstName and lastName, in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**in filter you must have the same type of object in other case you must map by property by property**

try in this way in your view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.firstName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.lastName" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in personList | filter:{firstName: search.firstName, lastName: search.lastName}">
        <td>
            <span class="col-xs-offset-2">
                {{person.firstName}}
            </span>
        </td>


        <td>
            <span class="col-xs-offset-2">
                {{person.lastName}}
            </span>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

**before using search variable** in your view **initialize it** in your controllar as

```
$scope.search = {firstName: '', lastName:''};
```

Comment: Yes, that was the reason, I had not defined the search object in the controller. Thanks for your response, Roberto noticed the same.